# Socket based event loop

Tags: c++, sockets, unix, event-loop

I want to setup server-client communication based on sockets. Clients can connect to server and receive different notifications from it. This can be implemented on client side as follows

```
...
Message* msg = NULL;
while ( msg = receiveMessage() )
    handleMessage( msg );
...
```

This code will be run in separated thread on client side and should handle different kinds of notification coming from server. But clients also should be able to communicate with socket by sending requests, i.e.

```
Request requestMsg;
if ( sendMessage( requestMsg ) )
{
    Message* response = receiveMessage();
    if ( response->type() == REQUEST_REPLY )
    ...
}
```

**Question:** How to achieve this? I don't want to interrupt reading thread, but i should receive response to specific request. This is local domain stream-based unix socket.

Answer (score 2):

...::: ASCII stuff below :::...

If you hate art, or ASCII stop here.

**The schematic below *will not* block the server nor the client.**
Many MMORPGS use this to secure the connection and make the protocol harder to crack.

```
     [================ ~~ Server ~~ ================]
     [ Select / Poll ]*4             5*[ Dispatcher ]
        ||      /\                             ||
        ||      ||                             ||
     *1 ||      ||2*                         *3||
        ||      ||                             ||
        \/      ||                             \/
     [ Thread 1 Basic IO ]       [ Thread 2 Listener]
     [=============== ~~ Client ~~ =================]

 *1 // send
 *2 // recv

 *3 // bind listen accept recv OR they will communicate using UDP
    // to a different port

 *4 // the server will process the clients normally
    // using select / poll / epoll / kqueue / `/dev/poll`

 *5 // The client will either setup a temporary server to process
    // the servers opcodes
 OR
    // It will accept UDP packets using recvfrom()

 *5 // I'd recommend using UDP so that the server can loop through the existing
    // connections and sendto() the opcodes which will be provided via a message
    // queue.
```

Answer (score 2):

In your receiver thread on the client, you should use a thread-safe object to push and pop messages.  If you have access to a C++11 compiler, You might consider `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Messsage>>`.  Here's a simple implementation of a thread-safe object that might suit your needs.

```
class MessageQueue
{
public:
  typedef std::shared_ptr<Message> SpMessage;

  bool empty() const {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
    return messages_.empty();
  }

  SpMessage pop() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
    SpMessage msg(messages_.front());
    messages_.pop_front();
    return msg;
  }

  void push(SpMessage const& msg)
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
    messages_.push_back(msg);
  }

private:
  MessageQueue(const MessageQueue&);  // disable 
  MessageQueue& operator=(const MessageQueue&);  // disable
  std::vector<SpMessage> messages_;
  std::mutex mutex_;
};

typedef std::shared_ptr<MessageQueue> SpMessageQueue;
```

At this point you have a sharable, thread-safe queue.  Share this queue between your main thread and your socket thread(s).  You could also use two if you want the sending to be on a separate thread as well, e.g., pop from one message queue, process it, and queue a response on the other queue.

You can use this same kind of thing for your server.

The message class should be able to store a `std::vector<char>` so that you can send/recv plain-old-data over the sockets and stuff into and pull out of a `Message` for processing.

If you need help on starting threads, check out this tutorial. http://solarianprogrammer.com/2011/12/16/cpp-11-thread-tutorial/

Comment: Is it possible to have a full example of using this MessageQueue class?